# Keep a background span div at bottom of page, not window

Tags: html, css

I have a `span` element which acts as a solid color background with a height of 300px. I want this span block to always be at the bottom of the page instead of the window/screen which is what is currently happening. Can someone help me?

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.blue-bg {
  background: #049ae6;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <section id="content">
    blah blah blah
  </section>
</div>
<span class="blue-bg"></span>
```

The content would overlap the span element near the bottom like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**:
`position: absolute` is correct, but:

> An element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed).
>   However; if an absolute positioned element has no positioned ancestors, it uses the document body, and moves along with page scrolling.

(https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

So, I introduces another wrapper element (#page) with an position of `relative`.

```css
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#page {
  position: relative;
}
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 1000px; /* to force scrolling */
    max-width: 800px;
}
.blue-bg {
    background: #049ae6;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
  <div id="page">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <section id="content">
          blah blah blah
      </section>
    </div>  
    <span class="blue-bg"></span>
  </div>
```

Comment: That still keeps the span element fixed to the bottom of the screen. So, on a mobile device, I'd like it to show up once the user scrolls all the way down.

Answer (score 0):

Change `position: absolute;` to `position: fixed`.

> position: fixed;
>
> An element with position: fixed; is positioned relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled. The top, right, bottom, and left properties are used to position the element.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: That still keeps the span element fixed to the bottom of the screen. So, on a mobile device, I'd like it to show up once the user scrolls all the way down.